# Refresh Issues When Using Different Browsers.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So pretty much my main question is how to fix this in a way that will work with each browser. I have a bunch of scripts on one page which when a button is clicked, will refresh the page, submit a form and update something in the database.

- When using Safari, all of this works smoothly and beautifully.
- When using Chrome, it causes a seizure warning, submits the form repetitively and you need to close the page.
- When using Firefox, I get a weird error, then it LOOKS like it refreshes once, but the script ran enough times to cause an error.

My goal to this question is that if I fix one of the scripts maybe all of them are similar in how I can solve them. One idea was that I had to use AJAX for it, but I'm not 100% sure if that's needed.

This is my code:

```
<div id="TameWindow" class="PopWindow">
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('TameWindow').style.display='none'">x</div>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Tame my horse <?php echo $HorseName ?><br/></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        Taming your horse allows you to be able to train them in specific skills and enter them in competitions.<br/>
        <form name="TameHorse" method="POST">
        <select id="TameDuration" name="TameDuration" onchange="TameInfo()">
          <option value=".5">30 mins
          <option value="1">1 hour
          <option value="1.5">1 hour 30 mins
          <option value="2">2 hours
          <option value="2.5">2 hour 30 mins
          <option value="3">3 hour
          <option value="3.5">3 hours 30 mins
          <option value="4">4 hours
          <option value="4.5">4 hours 30 mins
          <option value="5">5 hour     
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="TameSub" value="Tame">
        </form>
        <!--This is what displays on change of the variable -->
        <script>
        function TameInfo() 
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("TameDuration").value;
            var TameEnergy = x * 10;
            document.getElementById("TameInfo").innerHTML = "-" + TameEnergy + "% energy";
        }
        </script>
        <p id="TameInfo"></p>


        <!--This is the script to Tame the horse -->
        <?php
        $TDuration = $_POST['TameDuration'];
        $SubTame = $_POST['TameSub'];
                $IntellIncrease = $TDuration * 2;
                $EnergyDeduct = $TDuration *10;
                $TameIncrease = $TDuration *4;
            $TameEnergy = $Energy - $EnergyDeduct;
            $TameIntell = $Intell + $IntellIncrease;
            $TameGain = $Tame + $TameIncrease;  


        //This is the Query to update the horse's Energy, Intelligent points and Tame
        if($SubTame)
                {
                    if($TameEnergy <= 0)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <script>alert("Your horse doesn't have enough energy for that!");</script>
                        <?php
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $TameMyHorse = "UPDATE Horse SET Energy='$TameEnergy', IntelligenceP='$TameIntell', Taming='$TameGain' WHERE id='$colname_HorseInfo'";


                    if ($con->query($TameMyHorse) === TRUE)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <script>location.reload();</script>
                        <?php
                    } 
                    }
                }       
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if the error is JUST in my `location.reload()` script or if the whole thing needs to be re-written to work with multiple browsers. But I'd hate to delete all my code and start over if it's a simple fix I'm just not aware of.

Comment: Yes. You certainly need Ajax.

Comment: Like this: `function TameInfo()  {
            var x = $("#TameDuration").val();
            var TameEnergy = x * 10;
            $("TameInfo").html("-" + TameEnergy + "% energy");
            setTimeout(function() { $.post("train.php",{"TameDuration":x},function(values) { $("TameInfo").html("Energy:"+values.energy+"<br/>Deduct:"+values.deduct.....)},2000); });
        }`

Comment: @mplungjan would that get pasted in instead of certain code or would I add that in somewhere?

Comment: Replacing the function TameInfo - you need to modify your php that I call train.php for lack of name to deliver a json_encode(values) where values is an associative array with all the `{ IntellIncrease => $TDuration * 2,
                'EnergyDeduct' => $TDuration *10,
                'TameIncrease' =>$TDuration *4,
            'TameEnergy' => $Energy - $EnergyDeduct,
            'TameIntell' => $Intell + $IntellIncrease,
            'TameGain' => $Tame + $TameIncrease}`

Comment: @mplungjan and in the train.php file would I also include the update scripts?

Comment: Yes, but replace `if ($con->query($TameMyHorse) === TRUE)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <script>location.reload();</script>
                        <?php
                    } ` with `echo json_encode($values)`

Comment: and replace `if($TameEnergy <= 0)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <script>alert("Your horse doesn't have enough energy for that!");</script>
                        <?php
                    }` with `echo '{ values:{ error:"Your horse doesn't have enough energy for that!"}}';` and test values.error in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest you use Ajax. You tagged it jQuery so

1. replace `function TameInfo()` with something like

---

```
function TameInfo() { 
  var x = $("#TameDuration").val(); 
  var TameEnergy = x * 10; 
  $("TameInfo").html("-" + TameEnergy + "% energy"); // show the value
  setTimeout(function() { // give user time to see it 
    $.post("train.php",{"TameDuration":x},
      function(values) { 
        var message = values.error? values.error :
          "Increase:"+values.TameIncrease +
          "<br/>Deduct:"+va‌​lues.EnergyDeduct +
          ".....";
        $("TameInfo").html(message);
    }); 
  },2‌​000); 
}
```

2. train.php should be modified to deliver a json_encode(values) where values is an associative array with all the

---

```
if($TameEnergy <= 0) {
   $values = array('error'=>"Your horse doesn't have enough energy for that!");
 }
else {
  $values = array( 'IntellIncrease' => $TDuration * 2, 
    'EnergyDeduct' => $TDuration *10, 
    'TameIncrease' =>$TDuration *4, 
    'TameEnergy' => $Energy - $EnergyDeduct, 
    'TameIntell' => $Intell + $IntellIncrease, 
    'TameGain' => $Tame + $TameIncrease,
    'error'=>"");
    $TameMyHorse = "UPDATE Horse SET Energy='$TameEnergy', IntelligenceP='$TameIntell', Taming='$TameGain' WHERE id='$colname_HorseInfo'";

 }
 header("Content-type: application/json");
 echo json_encode($values);
```